# docker official dind build (docker:latest) with chromiuim

Tags: google-chrome, docker, dockerfile, chromium, alpine-linux

I've been trying for the last two days to get chromuim installed and running on docker:latest docker image. (docker in docker).

I have tried multiple docker files:

```
from docker:latest

RUN apk add --no-cache python py2-pip curl bash chromuim ttf-freefont xvfb nodejs nodejs-npm udev    
RUN curl -sSL https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash
ENV PATH $PATH:~/google-cloud-sdk/bin

RUN pip install docker-compose
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli swagger 
ENV CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/chromium-browser
```

This installed chrome 57, which doesn't support headless. 
So I suspect I can run this with xvbf, but running this chrome fails with:

```
Failed to move to new namespace: PID namespaces supported, Network namespace supported, but failed: errno = Operation not permitted
[8:8:1124/085514.600081:FATAL:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(182)] Check failed: ReceiveFixedMessage(fds[0], kZygoteBootMessage, sizeof(kZygoteBootMessage), &boot_pid). 
Aborted (core dumped)
```

So I tried to install chrome 61 (which supported headless).
But for that you need to update the Dockerfile to use edge.
I tried to upgrade / or install 61 right away. I always get fonts missing.
The closest I got was adjusting my dockerfile to use lighthose one

```
from docker:latest

RUN apk add --no-cache python py2-pip curl bash xvfb nodejs nodejs-npm udev    
RUN curl -sSL https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash
ENV PATH $PATH:~/google-cloud-sdk/bin

RUN pip install docker-compose
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli swagger 
ENV CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/chromium-browser

USER root

RUN echo "http://dl-2.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main" > /etc/apk/repositories
RUN echo "http://dl-2.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories
RUN echo "http://dl-2.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing" >> /etc/apk/repositories

#-----------------
# Set ENV and change mode
#-----------------
ENV LIGHTHOUSE_CHROMIUM_PATH /usr/bin/chromium-browser

ENV TZ "Europe/Berlin"
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV DEBCONF_NONINTERACTIVE_SEEN true
ENV SCREEN_WIDTH 750
ENV SCREEN_HEIGHT 1334
ENV SCREEN_DEPTH 24
ENV DISPLAY :99.0
ENV PATH /lighthouse/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

ENV GEOMETRY "$SCREEN_WIDTH""x""$SCREEN_HEIGHT""x""$SCREEN_DEPTH"

RUN echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

#-----------------
# Add packages
#-----------------

RUN apk -U --no-cache update
RUN apk -U --no-cache add \
    zlib-dev \
    chromium \
    freetype \
    ttf-opensans \
    xvfb \
    wait4ports \
    xorg-server \
    dbus \
    ttf-freefont \
    mesa-dri-swrast


# Minimize size

RUN apk del --purge --force curl make gcc g++ python linux-headers binutils-gold gnupg git zlib-dev apk-tools libc-utils

RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    /var/cache/apk/* \
    /usr/share/man \
    /tmp/* \
    /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/man \
    /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/doc \
    /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/html \
    /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/scripts

VOLUME /lighthouse/output

ADD xvfb-chromium.sh /chromium-xvfb.sh
RUN chmod +x /chromium-xvfb.sh
```

xvfb-chromium.sh (althought not need, as you can docker run /bin/bash into the container)

```
#!/bin/sh

_kill_procs() {
  kill -TERM $chromium
  wait $chromium
  kill -TERM $xvfb
}

parameters=$@


# We need to test if /var/run/dbus exists, since script will fail if it does not

[ ! -e /var/run/dbus ] && mkdir /var/run/dbus

/usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system

# Setup a trap to catch SIGTERM and relay it to child processes
trap _kill_procs SIGTERM

TMP_PROFILE_DIR=`mktemp -d -t chromium.XXXXXX`
export CHROME_DEBUGGING_PORT=9222

# Start Xvfb
Xvfb ${DISPLAY} -ac +iglx -screen 0 ${GEOMETRY} -nolisten tcp & xvfb=$!

printf "Starting xvfb window server..."

while [  1 -gt $xvfb  ]; do printf "..."; sleep 1; done

printf "xvfb started\n\n"

#printf "Starting chromium, with debugger on port $CHROME_DEBUGGING_POST...\n\n"

# --disable-webgl \

$CHROME_BIN \
--no-sandbox \
--user-data-dir=${TMP_PROFILE_DIR}  \
--start-maximized \
--remote-debugging-port=${CHROME_DEBUGGING_PORT} \
--no-first-run "about:blank" &

#chromium=$!

#wait4ports tcp://127.0.0.1:$CHROME_DEBUGGING_PORT

printf "\n\n==============================\nlaunching lighthouse run\n==============================\n\n"

#wait $chromium
wait $xvfb
```

Then I got another error:

```
Error relocating /usr/lib/chromium/chrome: FT_Set_Default_Properties: symbol not found
```

Not sure how to solve this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please provide chromium-xvfb.sh script as well

Comment: @Farhan that is not really import, you can docker run into the machine and try to run it, however I'll include in the question in one minute.

Comment: i am just going to reproduce this issue on my server. thats why i need that file to fully make it functional. so i can check root cause of issue

Comment: did you realize the typo there chromuim

Answer (score -1):

you could try this link https://github.com/c0b/chrome-in-docker 
It downloads a google-chrome Linux version from chrome channels, either stable, or beta, or developer version;It turns google-chrome into a headless browser,